# MacBook Air keyboard stops responding - forcing Finder to quit/restart fixes it. NSA or time for update?

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, macos

Roughly once a month my MacBook Air's keyboard stops responding. I have use of the trackpad/cursor but I can not type. I've found that going to Activity Monitor and forcing Finder to quit (and automatically restart) solves the problem.

Is this a known behavior? I'm currently running El Capitan 10.11.6, am I being hacked, or just the victim of an outdated system, or something else?

---

I'm not sure if I should use the `hang` tag - it is not application specific, rather it seems to be input device specific.

Comment: What model, precisely? Keyboards start/stopping can be a sign of a swollen battery, in need of replacement.

Comment: @Tetsujin yikes!  The little box says *MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012)* My battery is indeed old, I have a *Service Battery* warning, cycle count 333, 2775 mA capacity which seems reasonable considering the years of service this battery has given me. But I don't understand why restarting Finder would fix a mechanical issue like a swollen battery. That works every time, and involves only a few gentle swipes on the trackpad. I can try some mild bumping or light wiggling next time the problem occurs.

Comment: Not sure quite how that works, but I think it would be wise to get it looked at.

Comment: When it stops working, have you tried plugging in an external keyboard to see if the system is still responsive?

Comment: @Allan That's a great suggestion of something to try! But I don't have one - I live pretty light. I could borrow one (if I can find one) and keep it handy when I'm home. Do you have any thoughts what a positive or negative result might mean?

Comment: The built in keyboard is attached to the USB bus (you can see it in [System Report](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203001) >> USB) Plug in another USB keyboard and if it's software, it will affect both.  If it's hardware then only the bad one (internal) will be affected.

Comment: @Allan Right! I am always surprised when I re-discover that while poking around in the Hardware list, then I always forget it 5 minutes later. OK I'm going to see if I can find one. That's a great idea, thanks!